# What do you gain from the animal as a lycanthrope?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

So I have become a natural Lycanthrope via some in game shenanigans and looking into the template I found the wording to be a bit ambiguous.

> A lycanthrope retains all the special attacks, qualities, and abilities of the base creature. **In hybrid or animal form it gains the special attacks, qualities, and abilities of the base animal**. A lycanthrope also gains low-light vision, scent, and the following:

Emphasis mine.

What is meant by qualities? For the sake of simplicity lets say the character is a [were tiger.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/lycanthrope/weretiger) would I gain it's special abilities [Grab](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Grab-Ex-), [Pounce](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Pounce-Ex-), and [Rake](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Rake-Ex-). Would I also gain the [tigers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/cat-great/tiger) feats weapon focus, skill focus, and improved Initiative in hybrid/animal form?

Answer (score 3):

You gain exactly what the text states that you gain:

**Special Attacks**, which means that you indeed gain the special attacks *Grab*, *Pounce* and *Rake* once in either hybrid or animal form.

**Qualities**, by which is meant *Special Qualities*, are none for the tiger. However, if you look at the [Werecrocodile](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/lycanthrope/lycanthrope-werecrocodile), you see that when in hybrid and animal form, the character gains the special quality *Hold Breath*.

**Abilities** are also something you do not gain as a weretiger, because he has none. If we look at the [Wereboar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/lycanthrope/wereboar) however, we find that he gains *Ferocity* as an ability when he is in hybrid or animal form.

You do *not* gain the tiger's feats. If you want a Weapon Focus with claws, you would have to take the feat.